# Is it possible to check the SBS Backup log over RSS?

Tags: windows-server-2003, windows-sbs-2003

i am using a SBS 2003 and i would like to read the Backup log as a RSS/Atom Feed, are there any tools out there to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

The easist way would be to use the email notification option in SBS, and have it send email to some kind of social networking thing that can take email as input (posterous and probably twitter can do this), and just aggregate from there.